# Access Entities components via the Entity that holds them, or via a separate System?

Tags: game-design, component-based

Now, I'm implementing a component based game engine and I came to a thought: Which way should I access my components?

- Have a list of Entities, which have a list of Components, and access them by going trough each entity, and updating/drawing/whatever on each component.

or

- Have separate systems for each component type and acces them by going trough that systems components.

Or does it really matter? I think that the second way would seem faster...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend having *both*.

**Entity/Component Graph**

This defines which entities are attached to which components. In my engine, there is no such thing as an "entity", but any component can have child components. This graph is *not* used to draw or update components, but is only used for logical queries and events that are supposed to effect component sub-trees in the graph. The graph is just made of weak references to components (in C++, pointers. In other languages, unique identifiers), and doesn't contain the components itself.

For example, I have an "onDeath" event that uses the component graph to tell which components need to be destroyed when a parent component has died.

**Component Lists and Systems**

Parallel to the component graph is a set of component lists. For instance, there is a list of all the `Physics` components in the game, a list of all the `Sprite` components, and so on. These lists are aggregated into a big map of component type to component list called the `ComponentManager`.

`ComponentManager` is responsible for updating and drawing all components, one component type at a time. This is far faster than iterating through the component graph, because it has much better cache performance, and allows you to batch state of components before drawing/updating them.